# passing variable from twig JavaScript $.ajax to Symfony2 controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

(I've simplified the previous question)
I need to pass variable to Symfony2 controller using JavaScript, set that variable to session and then return session variable.

```
//test1.html.twig with $.ajax script and <input> tag.

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="#">
    <input type="number" class="inputISBN" name="name" 
         value="666" onchange="myFunction()">
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function myFunction() {
   var elementy = document.getElementsByClassName('inputISBN');
   var data = elementy[0].getAttribute('value');

   $.ajax({
        url: "{{ path('test') }}",
        type: "POST",
        data: data ,
        success: function() {alert("ok");}
    });   
}
</script>
```

Here are Actions in Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test1", name="test1")
 * @Template()
 */
public function test1Action()
{        
     return array();          
}


/**
 * @Route("/test", name="test")
 * @Template()
 */
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->request->get('data');        
    $session = $request->getSession();    
    $session->set('data',$data );
    return array();
}


 /**
 * @Route("/test2", name="test2")
 * @Template()
 */
public function test2Action(Request $request)
{       
    $session = $request->getSession();    
    $data = $session->get('data');        
    echo '<pre>',print_r($data),'</pre>';         
    return array();
}
```

I'm getting alert('ok') when changing value in input tag, but when opening test2Action site print_r($data) returns just 1.

Comment: did you clear cache after adding `testAction` to update routes? try to return some data in `testAction` like `return new Response("data set");` and catch it with ajax. so you will detect problem

Comment: Have you checked what is you getting in `testAction`? Test what you have in session just after setting the `data` value in the session using `$session->get('data');`

Answer (score 0):

It's working when I change `data: data` to `data: { "data": data }` in

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "{{ path('test') }}",
        type: "POST",
        data: data ,
        success: function() {alert("ok");}
    });
```

Comment: Might want to lookup the basics of json.  Might also try pressing F12 in your browser and then clicking on the network tab.  You can actually see what is being sent between the browser and the server.

Answer (score 0):

The route is wrong in th ajax's url:

```
url: "{{ path('test') }}",
```

Must be:

```
url: "{{ path('test1') }}",
```